# can't properly shutdown ubuntu and sound problem on HP mini 311 netbook

Tags: linux, audio, ubuntu-10.04, shutdown, alsa

I recently bought a HP mini 311 netbook. I replaced its harddrive and installed ubuntu 10.04. Since then, I have encountered some very strange problem with its sound and shutdown/reboot.

At times, when I start the computer, it will have no sound, on the GUI the sound is at max, but no sound is available. This sometimes also happen after after upgrades, hibernate, and toggling the wireless radio button.

Strangely, when the sound is out the device will also refuse to be shutdown. If I shutdown the computer using the GUI, it will simply go back to the log in screen without actually shutting down. If I use "sudo shutdown 0", the computer will hang on the loading screen of the shut down process. I had to force the pc to shutdown by holding the power button down.

Usually (probably always) after I force a turn-off then start off again. the sound and shutdown become normal. I wonder if anyone have clues regarding to the cause of this problem.

This the info about the computer:

1. Installed Ubuntu 10.04LTS RC, later upgraded to formal released version.
2. cat /proc/asound/version == "Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.21." however, when doing 'alsaconf' the version displayed is 1.0.23

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This might be bug #544139,
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/consolekit/+bug/544139

Check it out to see if it matches your symptoms.